# Declaring static auto function pointers in traits template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a couple of functions for different data types that I want to use in a template depending on the data type of the template parameter. I declared a helper template struct `traits` and specialized it for the corresponding data types.

My question is: is it possible to avoid writing the exact function signatures in these specializations? Additionally, is it possible to avoid defining these functions outside of the template declaration and still have them `static`?

The very simplified example of what I want to do is below. The syntax that I would *like* to use is commented out, but it clearly doesn't compile.

```
#include <iostream>

int f() { return 1; }
double g() { return 2.3; }

template<typename T>
struct traits;

template<>
struct traits<int> {
    // static auto func = f;
    int(*func)() = f;
};

template<>
struct traits<double> {
    // static auto func = g;
    double(*func)() = g;
};

template<typename T>
struct traits_user {
    void output() {
        // std::cout << traits<T>::func() << " ";
        std::cout << traits<T>().func() << " ";
    }
};


int main()
{
    traits_user<int>().output();
    traits_user<double>().output();
}
```

**Edit** 
While answer by @RSahu is actually perfect, I cannot use it because I'm stuck with VS2013 for some time more. A solution suitable for VS2013 would be very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
static auto constexpr func = f;
```

and

```
static auto constexpr func = g;
```

I got the following error in g++ when I tried to compile without the `constexpr`.

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall    socc.cc   -o socc
socc.cc:17:24: error: ‘constexpr’ needed for in-class initialization of static data member ‘double (* traits<double>::func)()’ of non-integral type [-fpermissive]
     static auto func = g;
```

Without support for `constexpr`, one work around is:

```
template<>
struct traits<int> {
   static double func()
   {
      return f();
   }
};

template<>
struct traits<double> {
   static double func()
   {
      return g();
   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'm stuck with VS2013 for now and it doesn't have support for constexpr. Any other ideas? I edited the answer and +1'd you.

Comment: So I guess there's no way around repeating the function signature (they are of course much more elaborate in my real code). Is this correct?

Comment: @Rostislav, since VS2013 doesn't support all the C++11 features, I find it hard to suggest a different work around. It doesn't help that I don't have quick access to VS2013.

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunate that I can't switch to a much more conformant VS2015 - probably will do as soon as Qt provides binaries for it. I'll keep the question open for a bit more and if no one has other ideas - I'll accept your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use auto, you can probably still use decltype and a type alias:

```
template<> struct traits<int> {
    using F  = decltype(&f); 
    const static F func; 
}; 
const traits<int>::F traits<int>::func= f;
```

Whether that is better or worse than the explicit approach is for you to decide.

You can of course also omit the type alias, if you don't need it anywhere else:

```
template<> struct traits<int> {
    const static decltype(&f) func;
};
const decltype(&f) traits<int>::func = f;
```